# HTML-страница не может получить доступ к переменной в конструкторе класса typescript. Unresolved variable

Tags: angular4, webstorm, аутентификация

Код на Angular4. С помощью оператора ngIf нужно проверить на наличие аутентикации. Данную проверку выполняет метод, находящийся в сервисе, созданном специально для этого. На этот сервис ссылается typescript-код. В конструкторе создается соответствующая переменная. Если ее значение положительное выводятся/не выводятся элементы списка, ответсвенные за логин. 
Webstorm пишет "unresolved variable", логика при этом не работает. Ошибка в консоль не поступает.
Вот шаблон:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="navbar-header">
  <a routerLink="/" class="navbar-brand">Recipe Book</a>
 </div>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/recipes">Recipies</a></li>
   <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/shopping-list" >Shopping List</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <ng-template [ngIf]="!authService.isAuthenticated()">
        <li><a routerLink="/signup">Register</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/signin">LogIn</a></li>
      </ng-template>
   <li class="dropdown" app-dropdown>
    <a style="cursor: pointer" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" *ngIf="authService.isAuthenticated()">Manage <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a style="cursor: pointer" (click)="OnSave()">Save Data</a></li>
     <li><a style="cursor: pointer" (click)="OnGet()">Fetch Data</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

вот typescript-код компонента:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import {RecipeDataService} from '../shared/RecipeData.service';
import {SignupUserService} from '../auth/signupUser.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  constructor(private RecipeDataService: RecipeDataService,
              private authService: SignupUserService) { }
  OnSave()
  {
    this.RecipeDataService.OnSaveRecipe()
      .subscribe(
        (response: Response) =>
        {
          console.log(response);
        }
      );
  }
  OnGet()
  {
    this.RecipeDataService.OnGettingRecipe();
  }




}

И содержимое сервиса, на который ссылаюсь: 
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';


@Injectable()

export class SignupUserService {
  token = '';
  signUpUser(email: string, password: string) {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch(
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }
  signInUser(email: string, password: string)
  {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(
        response => {
          firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
            .then(
              (token: string) => this.token = token
            );
        }
        )
      .catch (
        error => {console.log(error); }
      );
  }
  getToken() {
    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
      .then(
        (token: string) => this.token = token
      );
    return this.token;
  }
  isAuthenticated(): boolean
  {
    return this.token != null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(private RecipeDataService: RecipeDataService,
              public authService: SignupUserService) { }
```

public будет доступен везде а private только внутри этого class

[Методы доступа](https://habrahabr.ru/post/21357/) - Изучайте

Comment: Добавь описание, почему это должно помочь

Comment: На самом деле `private` также доступен в шаблоне. просто webstorm Не может в ангуляр